# HTML to run mp4 video on Windows - Avoid restriction in IE

Tags: html, video

The HTML file below runs the video just fine when opened in Edge, new Windows 10 browser.  But in IE, also on Windows 10, I get this message: "Internet Explorer restricted this webpage from running scripts or ActiveX controls."  I believe this may be the reason my LiveCode script fails to open the HTML page, because it relies on IE resources.  I read there may be a security issue with playing videos directly.  The video may need to be loaded into a cache and the path to that used instead of direct path to the video file residing in the same directory as the HTML file.  Does anyone have HTML to do this, if this is right?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body>
<p><video width=”320″ height=”240″ controls>
<source src="TestVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src=”TestVideo.ogg” type=”video/ogg”>
Your browser does not support the video tag.  </video>
</p>
<p>
</p>
</body> 
</html>
```

My goal is to run mp4 videos in HTML5, which I understand is a pretty universal platform now for video playback.

Comment: html5 has a video tag, but never specified what video codecs should be supported. it's basically platform neutral. there is NO guarantee what codecs (and therefore, what file types) are playable on any particular system.

Comment: _“I believe this may be the reason my LiveCode script fails to open the HTML page”_ – what LiveCode script?

Comment: This is the LiveCard script: 

    put revBrowserOpenCef(the windowId of this stack, tPath) into tBrowserID
    revBrowserSet tBrowserID, "rect", the rect of graphic "browserPlaceholder"

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the version of Chromium browser in LiveCode does not support h.264 mp4 video.  It does support WebM video and tested great on Mac X and Windows 10, presumably back to Windows 7.  WebM video is comparable in quality and file size to h.264.  Tested the LiveCode browser at http://html5test.com.  HTML file that plays WebM video on Windows and Mac from LiveCode:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
 <html> 
 <body>
 <p><video autoplay controls>
 <source src="small.webm" type="video/webm" />
 Your browser does not support the video tag. </video>
 </p>
 <p>
 </p>
 </body> 
 </html>
```

LiveCode script:

```
put revBrowserOpenCef(the windowId of this stack, tPath) into tBrowserID
revBrowserSet tBrowserID, "rect", the rect of graphic "browserPlaceholder"
```